# magento 500 internal server error suddenly after changing store url in multisite

Tags: magento-1.8, category, multistore, products

I have setup multiple stores in magento. When I went to System-> Configuration ->mystore2-> Web -> and Changed url and rewrite settings, the whole site with backend magento disappeared. Now it shows only 500 internal server error and I dont know what to do?

Your help is appreciated

.htaccess file

```
    ############################################
## uncomment these lines for CGI mode
## make sure to specify the correct cgi php binary file name
## it might be /cgi-bin/php-cgi

#    Action php5-cgi /cgi-bin/php5-cgi
#    AddHandler php5-cgi .php

############################################
## GoDaddy specific options

#   Options -MultiViews

## you might also need to add this line to php.ini
##     cgi.fix_pathinfo = 1
## if it still doesn't work, rename php.ini to php5.ini

############################################
## this line is specific for 1and1 hosting

    #AddType x-mapp-php5 .php
    #AddHandler x-mapp-php5 .php

############################################
## default index file

    DirectoryIndex index.php

<IfModule mod_php5.c>

############################################
## adjust memory limit

#    php_value memory_limit 64M
    php_value memory_limit 256M
    php_value max_execution_time 18000

############################################
## disable magic quotes for php request vars

    php_flag magic_quotes_gpc off

############################################
## disable automatic session start
## before autoload was initialized

    php_flag session.auto_start off

############################################
## enable resulting html compression

    #php_flag zlib.output_compression on

###########################################
# disable user agent verification to not break multiple image upload

    php_flag suhosin.session.cryptua off

###########################################
# turn off compatibility with PHP4 when dealing with objects

    php_flag zend.ze1_compatibility_mode Off

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_security.c>
###########################################
# disable POST processing to not break multiple image upload

    SecFilterEngine Off
    SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>

############################################
## enable apache served files compression
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#gzip

    # Insert filter on all content
    ###SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
    # Insert filter on selected content types only
    #AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css text/javascript

    # Netscape 4.x has some problems...
    #BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html

    # Netscape 4.06-4.08 have some more problems
    #BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip

    # MSIE masquerades as Netscape, but it is fine
    #BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html

    # Don't compress images
    #SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip dont-vary

    # Make sure proxies don't deliver the wrong content
    #Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>

############################################
## make HTTPS env vars available for CGI mode

    SSLOptions StdEnvVars

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

############################################
## enable rewrites

    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on

############################################
## you can put here your magento root folder
## path relative to web root

   # RewriteBase

############################################
## uncomment next line to enable light API calls processing

#    RewriteRule ^api/([a-z][0-9a-z_]+)/?$ api.php?type=$1 [QSA,L]

############################################
## rewrite API2 calls to api.php (by now it is REST only)

    RewriteRule ^api/rest api.php?type=rest [QSA,L]

############################################
## workaround for HTTP authorization
## in CGI environment

    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

############################################
## TRACE and TRACK HTTP methods disabled to prevent XSS attacks

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^TRAC[EK]
    RewriteRule .* - [L,R=405]

############################################
## redirect for mobile user agents

    #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mobiledirectoryhere/.*$
    #RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC]
    #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mobiledirectoryhere/ [L,R=302]

############################################
## always send 404 on missing files in these folders

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(media|skin|js)/

############################################
## never rewrite for existing files, directories and links

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

############################################
## rewrite everything else to index.php

    RewriteRule .* index.php [L]

</IfModule>


############################################
## Prevent character encoding issues from server overrides
## If you still have problems, use the second line instead

    AddDefaultCharset Off
    #AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

<IfModule mod_expires.c>

############################################
## Add default Expires header
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#expires

    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"

</IfModule>

############################################
## By default allow all access

    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all

###########################################
## Deny access to release notes to prevent disclosure of the installed Magento version

    <Files RELEASE_NOTES.txt>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </Files>

############################################
## If running in cluster environment, uncomment this
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#etags

    #FileETag none

##start blocking potentially unwanted bots. 
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^BlackWidow [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Bot\ mailto:craftbot@yahoo.com [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^ChinaClaw [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Custo [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^DISCo [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Download\ Demon [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^eCatch [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^EirGrabber [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^EmailSiphon [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^EmailWolf [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Express\ WebPictures [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^ExtractorPro [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^EyeNetIE [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^FlashGet [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^GetRight [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^GetWeb! [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Go!Zilla [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Go-Ahead-Got-It [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^GrabNet [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Grafula [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^HMView [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} HTTrack [NC,OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Image\ Stripper [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Image\ Sucker [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Indy\ Library [NC,OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^InterGET [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Internet\ Ninja [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^JetCar [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^JOC\ Web\ Spider [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^larbin [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^LeechFTP [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Mass\ Downloader [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^MIDown\ tool [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Mister\ PiX [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Navroad [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^NearSite [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^NetAnts [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^NetSpider [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Net\ Vampire [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^NetZIP [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Octopus [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Offline\ Explorer [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Offline\ Navigator [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^PageGrabber [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Papa\ Foto [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^pavuk [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^pcBrowser [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^RealDownload [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^ReGet [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^SiteSnagger [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^SmartDownload [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^SuperBot [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^SuperHTTP [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Surfbot [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^tAkeOut [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Teleport\ Pro [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^VoidEYE [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Web\ Image\ Collector [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Web\ Sucker [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebAuto [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebCopier [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebFetch [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebGo\ IS [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebLeacher [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebReaper [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebSauger [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Website\ eXtractor [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Website\ Quester [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebStripper [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebWhacker [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebZIP [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Wget [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Widow [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WWWOFFLE [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Xaldon\ WebSpider [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Zeus 
RewriteRule ^.* - [F,L] 
##end code. bye bots.
```

error_log file in public_html folder

```
    [26-May-2015 05:04:25 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away' in /home3/xxxx/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228
Stack trace:
#0 /home3/xxxx/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php(228): PDOStatement->execute(Array)
#1 /home3/xxxx/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#2 /home3/xxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#3 /home3/xxxx/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#4 /home3/xxxx/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT RELEASE_...', Array)
#5 /home3/xxxx/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(428): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT RELEASE_...', Array)
#6 /home3/xxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Resource/Helper/ in /home3/xxxx/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php on line 235
[26-May-2015 06:04:27 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away' in /home3/xxxx/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228
Stack trace:
#0 /home3/xxxx/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php(228): PDOStatement->execute(Array)
#1 /home3/xxxx/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#2 /home3/xxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#3 /home3/xxxx/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#4 /home3/xxxx/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT RELEASE_...', Array)
#5 /home3/xxxx/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(428): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT RELEASE_...', Array)
#6 /home3/xxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Resource/Helper/ in /home3/xxxx/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php on line 235
[26-May-2015 07:17:24 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getBackend() on a non-object in /home/xxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php on line 816
[26-May-2015 07:17:39 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getBackend() on a non-object in /home/xxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php on line 816
[26-May-2015 07:18:09 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getBackend() on a non-object in /home/xxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php on line 816
[26-May-2015 07:18:52 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getBackend() on a non-object in /home/xxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php on line 816
[26-May-2015 07:20:20 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getBackend() on a non-object in /home/xxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php on line 816
[26-May-2015 07:21:31 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getBackend() on a non-object in /home/xxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php on line 816
[26-May-2015 08:59:07 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getBackend() on a non-object in /home/xxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php on line 816
[26-May-2015 09:55:02 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getBackend() on a non-object in /home/xxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php on line 816
[26-May-2015 09:56:17 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getBackend() on a non-object in /home/xxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php on line 816
[26-May-2015 09:56:21 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getBackend() on a non-object in /home/xxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php on line 816
[26-May-2015 09:57:04 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getBackend() on a non-object in /home/xxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php on line 816
[26-May-2015 09:59:59 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getBackend() on a non-object in /home/xxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php on line 816
[26-May-2015 10:07:30 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getBackend() on a non-object in /home/xxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php on line 816
[26-May-2015 10:44:39 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getBackend() on a non-object in /home/xxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php on line 816
[26-May-2015 10:45:11 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getBackend() on a non-object in /home/xxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php on line 816
[26-May-2015 10:45:25 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getBackend() on a non-object in /home/xxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php on line 816
[26-May-2015 10:46:14 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getBackend() on a non-object in /home/xxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php on line 816
[26-May-2015 10:48:23 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getBackend() on a non-object in /home/xxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php on line 816
[26-May-2015 10:53:26 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getBackend() on a non-object in /home/xxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php on line 816
[26-May-2015 10:54:03 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getBackend() on a non-object in /home/xxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php on line 816
[26-May-2015 10:58:35 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getBackend() on a non-object in /home/xxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php on line 816
[27-May-2015 08:43:36 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getBackend() on a non-object in /home/xxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php on line 816
[28-May-2015 06:04:47 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away' in /home3/xxxx/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228
Stack trace:
#0 /home3/xxxx/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php(228): PDOStatement->execute(Array)
#1 /home3/xxxx/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#2 /home3/xxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#3 /home3/xxxx/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#4 /home3/xxxx/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT RELEASE_...', Array)
#5 /home3/xxxx/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(428): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT RELEASE_...', Array)
#6 /home3/xxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Resource/Helper/ in /home3/xxxx/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php on line 235
[
```

Comment: Try to remove .htaccess file.

Comment: It did not work

Comment: Note that Magento Connect Manager is working in directory /downloader

Comment: Check your server error log and add the error to your question

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism can you check it now?

Comment: @VashikaranSamrat those errors are from May 2015 they won't help unfortunately

Comment: I just tried to update the base url of another store I have created.  Before doing it, everything was working fine. I dont have access to backend admin panel as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to phpmyadmin and open your mysql database. Go to core_config_data table and check for the URL you have changed with scope_id 2. This will be the URL of another store you have created. Delete those URLs, and set the value of web_seo_rewrites to '0' for again scope_id 2. This might work for you.

Comment: let me try if it works...

Comment: Hey man you are just awesome... It worked... Thanks